# What is the best way to establish communication between silverlight controls and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, user-controls

I thought I ask the more exprienced Silverlight users about what they think is the best way to embed Silverlight user controls into an ASP.NET page - in special regards to stablish an easy way of communication between the conrols.

I have heard about services, query strings, etc. but I'd like to find out what has worked for you the best so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at WCF RIA Services.  It provides a way for ASP.NET to expose methods and data entities and expose them to Silverlight automatically.  RIA Services creates proxy objects on the Silverlight side and wires them up with WCF services without you having to do any work.  It is pretty slick.

Here is a starting point.  Beware: the learning curve is kind of steep.  But it is rewarding once you get there.

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/

Also, another thing to watch out for is that some of those articles refer to beta/CTP versions and some of the namespaces changed before it went to production.

Comment: Thanks for this. It isn't very complicated and works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the below article which uses event aggregation to communicate.. i found this useful..
http://blog.weareon.net/how-to-communicate-between-two-user-controls-using-event-aggregator/